# unboundlocalerror with displaying output

Tags: python

Rock paper scissors, when I run it the program is saying decision is referenced before it is assigned although userchoice and computer choice are displaying fine, I've been stuck on this for quite some time and am new to programming.

```
import random

def main():
   userinput = int(input("First just enter 0 for rock, 1 for paper, or 2 for scissors! "))
   computernumber = random.randint(0,2)
   while userinput != 0 and userinput != 1 and userinput != 2:
      userinput = int(input("Enter 0 for rock, 1 for paper, or 2 for scissors! "))
   print ("You chose ",userchoice(userinput),)
   print ("Computer chose ",computerchoice(computernumber),)  
   print (decision(userchoice,computerchoice))

def userchoice(userinput):
   if userinput == 0:
      userchoice = "rock";
   elif userinput == 1:
      userchoice = "paper";
   elif userinput == 2:
      userchoice = "scissors";
   return userchoice

def computerchoice(computernumber):

   if computernumber == 0:
      computerchoice = "rock";
   elif computernumber == 1:
      computerchoice = "paper";
   elif computernumber == 2:
      computerchoice = "scissors";
   return computerchoice   

def decision(userchoice,computerchoice):

   if (userchoice == computerchoice):
      decision = "It's a draw!";
   elif (userchoice == "rock"):
      if(computerchoice == "paper"):
         decision = "Computer wins!";
   elif (userchoice == "paper"):
      if(computerchoice == "rock"):
         decision = "You win!";
      else:
         decision = "Computer wins!";   
   elif (userchoice == "scissors"):
      if(computerchoice == "rock"):
         decision = "Computer wins!";
      else:
         decision = "You win!";
   return decision


main()
```

output:

```
first just enter 0 for rock, 1 for paper, or 2 for scissors! 1
You chose  paper
Computer chose  rock
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MorerockpaperscissorsEM.py", line 60, in <module>
    main()
  File "MorerockpaperscissorsEM.py", line 17, in main
    print(decision(userchoice,computerchoice))
  File "MorerockpaperscissorsEM.py", line 57, in decision
    return decision
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'decision' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: What is the traceback you are getting? One problem may be that you are reusing the name of the function `userchoice` both as a local variable inside the function (which may be OK; it just prevents you from being able to call the function recursively) and also as the argument to `decision` (which is more likely to be a logic error).

Comment: I added the traceback

Answer (score 1):

When calling the 'decision' function in this line

```
print (decision(userchoice,computerchoice))
```

you are passing the functions 'userchoice' and 'computerchoice' as arguments. The correct way to call this function would be:

```
print (decision(userchoice(userinput),computerchoice(computernumber)))
```

Comment: Note that this also is the underlying cause of the actual traceback; since you pass a function reference instead of a string, none of the conditions in the function `decision` succeed, so the value of the variable `decision` is never set before you return it.